# Quota exceeded with openshift

Tags: git, openshift

I am trying to tidy my openshift app because of quota exceeded. I am running

```
rhc app-tidy <apname>
```

and I get the following

```
Warning: Gear 53ccc6c25973ca3f06000306 is using 100.0% of disk quota
Failed to execute: 'control start' for
/var/lib/openshift/53ccc6c25973ca3f06000306/haproxy
```

I tried to delete some files locally and push the changes to delete them from the server too but It won't let me.

```
remote: error: unable to create temporary file: ??????????? ?? ???? ?????? ??????
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To ssh://gearid@domain.name/~/git/beta.git/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gearid@domain.name~/git/beta.git/'
```

Can I remove them from the server manually and run git push after that? Or will this cause trouble to the git history and syncs?

Comment: You should try sshing to your gear and removing files manually until you can do a git push, then maybe you can run a "git prune" on your repo and see if that helps.

Comment: locally?or should I log to my openshift account and run it there?

Answer (score 0):

You can access ssh and delete the ROOT.war in webapps dir in your server folder

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. All my logs folders was clean.
I connected into cartridge with ssh and found that almost all space used by git repo. I could not even run "git gc" because it needs disk space too.

Than I removed ".git" folder and reinitialised my git repo. And tried to push my new repo, but got an error about disk quota exided again.

So my next decision wa a little bit reckless, but it helped for me:

1. I connected with ssh again: `rhc ssh %appName%`
2. Changed dir to git objects dir: `cd git/appName.git/objects`
3. And removed all thngs inside it: `yes | rm -r *`
4. Than pushed my recreated git repo.

Probably it could corrupt my repo, because when I run a `git gc` it shows me a warnings:

`warning: reflog of 'refs/heads/master' references pruned commits
 warning: reflog of 'HEAD' references pruned commits`

And despite that git finished "gc" operation.